# Difference in creating folders on files GUI and cmd line

Tags: partitioning, mount, files, filesystem, filemanager

I have an NTFS partition which is accessible to both my linux (ubuntu 17) and Windows 10 OS's. Today I accessed the drive in windows 10 a fair bit, and rebooted into linux to use it.

I still have fast boot enabled in Windows 10 (so it does that sort of hibernate thing) and I have problems where the entire NTFS partition was mounted as readonly.

After some googling, I entered a command which errored in a way that tipped me off that it was the windows hibernation thing.
I wanted to find a good solution such that I could continue using windows as I do, with the fast boot on.

I found a command after googling further that appeared that appeared to be a solution, something I may just need to enter each time I boot into linux and wish to use the NTFS partition.

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc3`

Where `/dev/sdc3` is the NTFS partition.

This appeared to fix things, however I have a weird situation where I cannot create folders (or files I assume), or move them, via the file manager GUI, but I can rename them via it. using `mv` and `mkdir` commands in terminal however works fine.

Upon going back to check /etc/fstab I have `UUID=blah-UID-replaced /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`

In between shutting down Windows and booting up Linux, I also connected a new SSD linux hadn't seen before, so I don't know if that is also contributing to this.

Would be great if I knew what I should be doing to just be using Linux properly / normally again...

Thanks!

Comment: So, the problem with ntfs and fastboot is that Windows keeps an image of the drives and write cache in memory when it hibernates (fastboot) - writing to an ntfs disk under these conditions can cause corruption that probably Windows can handle when it turns back on.  The one time it can't handle it though, will become a real problem for you.

Comment: So... the system doesn't support something (modifying a filesystem marked dirty), you try to make it do so regardless, and things don't behave consistently and you ask why? O.o